# Data synchronizing with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

I was just about to buy redgate.com's compare package when I came to realize it seems highly unlikely a task like this isn't something that can be performed from the Management Studio.

I have a development database and I have a live database.
I develop my application adding stored procedures, correcting small things in the data structure and maybe add some new tables.
Now I want the changes added to the live server. As it is unlikely I have kept 100% track of all of my changes I would of course like if it just new itself what I have changed.

Does anyone know what's best practice in Management Studio for this task? I mean it must be a task we all gets confronted with in larger projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it with management studio it's all restricted to your own head. YOU will have to keep track of all the changes etc. I find that Redgates SQL Compare 8 and SQL Data Compare 7 does the trick. I recently moved the structure of a production database over to something totally different within minutes thanks to Redgate.

I have earlier tried to use Management Studio but it does not perform very well at complex tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be keeping your database schema in version control along with your source code.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with it not being in the IDE? It has its own interface.

This tool save me hours a day. Not only because I dont HAVE to remember everything, but I then dont have to fix the production server if I missed something. I can work on multiple systems and push updates to each of them in a 10th of the time it would take me in the Management Studio.

This tool is by far the best 3rd party tool ive used for sql server. Its a godsend. A cheap one at that.

Just dont have the arrow pointing the wrong way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just bought Redgate :)

I have worked with it before so i can only agree that it is state of the art, I was just stunned to realize that Management Studio don't have anything that corresponds to this.

Thanks for the great answers! 
Stackoverflow really is the pleace to ask these kinda things.